# Button Click vs ShortCut Key (ALT) Event firing order

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, events

I have a *Save* button on a form with a shortcut key set (ALT+S).
In my `datagrid` in the `cellvalidated` event I make a determination if I can enable or disable this button for the users.

Similar to the old VB6 problem of Event firing order....
If the button was currently enabled, but user puts invalid data in the datagrid cell. If they *Click* on the button, the cell validated event fires, disables the button - no issue. When, instead, they input the bad data, and do ALT+S, the cell validated event fires, but in this case the `Button_Click` event still fires.

Any way to prevent this?  Basically if the use the ALT+, I don't want the *Click* event to fire.

Comment: One thing you can do is to validate on `Button_click` insted of `cell_validate`. In this case, you will need a method `IsCellValid(cell) as boolean`. In button click you will do `if not IsCellValid(cell) then <focus on cell> return`.... Also, what about check in `button.click` - `if not button.enabled then return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything else fails - there is this method (in pseudo-code)

```
Class Form

    private _validated as Boolean

    sub Cell_validate

        ' validate here and set
        _validated = true/false
    end sub

    sub Button_Click

        If not _validated then Return

        ' have your save logic here
    end sub          

End class
```

This way you will protect your code from executing actual logic of `Button_Click` when button disabled.